# Storyboard segue push along with plist overwrite

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, segue

I was using storyboard segue to push from one view "controller A" to view "controller B" with a "button".
at the same, "button" call [self writeToPlist] to overwrite "value 1" to "value 2" on a plist.
after that,"view controller B" will display the "value 2" from plist.

the problem is it seems like the plist was overwritten AFTER "view controller B" loaded.
so "view controller B" will just display the "value 1",
"value 2" was written after that.

how can i solve it,i have no idea how it should be.thanks

Comment: Please include the code where you are trying to do this - presumably the button action, any prepareForSegue method, and possibly the viewDidload or viewWillAppear of your second view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wire your button to an IBAction method in code, perform the file change, then call performSegueWithIdentifier: method to force the transition, it should be fine.

Comment: If it solved your issue, please mark it as answered so other people know it was the correct answer.  Cheers!